# Decrypt >4GB files on Windows

Tags: windows-10, pgp, decryption, openpgp

I am trying to decrypt a bunch of large encrypted files (some are > 4GB) on Windows 10 (64 bit). I have been given the instructions to double click on each file then a "PGP Self Decrypting Archive" window would open and ask to "Enter Passphrase".

I am aware now that [PGP Self Decrypting Archives file sizes are limited to 4GB](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/153717/pgp-selfdecrypting-archive-size-limitati.html). Is there any way possible to decrypt the >4GB files on Windows or other OS (if possible), at all??

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/156577/bug-report-pgp-commandline-creates-sda-f.html) is what you need

Comment: @davidgo a small window pops up and says "This app can't run on your PC - Tp find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher".

Comment: Try it on a 64-bit version of Windows.  Optionally, for code trust, add the code-signing certificate to your "Trusted Publishers" certificate store in Windows.

Comment: Thanks @leeharvey ! I have been running it on Windows 64 bits.